# How to create a div based on user entered values

Tags: asp.net

I am working on a web development project in asp.net dealing with generating a image based on the user entered length and width.
Mainly we provide them in CSS style
but can we accomplish the same in creating an image with user entered values?

Comment: What you did and now wants to do..can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether this is useful for you. This sample application allows the user to set the dimensions for the image to be re sized & uploaded. Also the re sized image is converted into PNG image format.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4097/Dynamically-resize-uploaded-images-save-in-PNG-for